# How to speed up Java Project by moving files to Ramdisk?

Tags: performance, ramdisk

I have a simple maven - Java EE web application which I develop using IntelliJ and deploy to Glassfish server. The thing is, it takes about 15 seconds to deploy. I know it is not too long, but I am trying to make it even faster.

I installed RAMDISK and moved my project into that disk, it did not help. Then I moved Glassfish in the RAMDISK as well, however there was still no change in the performance.

Do I need to move JDK, JRE to the RAMDISK as well to see the change? Or even the IDE itself?

Why did not moving the project and the glassfish to RAMDISK make any change?

Comment: Since you have done all those things, perhaps - just perhaps - disk speed isn't the issue here?

Comment: @Dariusz I am not sure if you mean it or you are mocking me, then is it the processor speed? Or maybe the cache size?

Comment: The first law on performance optimization: 'The bottleneck is never where you think it is, not even close'

Comment: [3.Identify the part of the system that is critical for improving the performance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Performance_tuning)

Comment: @KorayTugay both. You apparently spent a lot of your time "speeding up" the startup without even knowing *what* really takes most time during the process. You should spend your time determining what is going slowly - and then, probably, you'd be able to fix the problem in minutes (or not be able to fix it at all, but it's still a valid definite answer).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps your speed problem is not related to the disk.  Maybe use a [profiler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profiling_%28computer_programming%29) to see where the time is actually being spent, and then optimize the slowest part.  Repeat until startup is fast enough.